# mysql full text search ampersand (&) Problem

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, ampersand

How can I serach word with "&" using mysql full text search ?

There are words string, like "Marks & Spencer", "at&t" in my tables , serach "at&t", but can't find it on the database using mysql full text search

Any ways to serach word with "&"?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible. "&" is treated as an operator: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html

There used to be a bug filled for this exact thing: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=26265

Comment: Even if it is within quotes? `WHERE company LIKE 'at&t'` ? That's no good.

Comment: Basically I don't think there is a way you can escape it.

Answer (score -1):

solved it. Just using REPAIR TABLE

Comment: Can you elaborate? (For the record)

Comment: I would be also very interested how REPAIR TABLE helped you to solve this?

Comment: set up configuration: set up minimum word length value as 1; and then REPAIR TABLE; That is what we did